# Secure connection/encryption using sqlalchemy/pyodbc/pymssql

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, pymssql

I am using *sqlalchemy/pyodbc* to communicate with sql server. I am facing the following problem - Some of the functionalities involve uploading sensible information to the server and secure connection/data encryption is needed.

I was suggested to use *FreeTDS+pymssql*. Can someone explain what is the idea behind it(how does it work) and more importantly is there a solution that doesn't involve switching to *pymssql* but rather staying with *pyodbc*.

Another question is also - Does anyone have information regarding the uploading speed of *pyodbc* compared to *pymssql*. I know that in the past *pymssql* was underperforming.

```
    self.engine = sal.create_engine(f'@{server}/{database}?trusted_connection=YES &driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server',poolclass=NullPool)
    self.conn = self.engine.connect()
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064792/2144390

Comment: Microsoft's "ODBC Driver xx for SQL Server" will use an encrypted connection if the server requires it. For best results you should use the latest version, currently "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server". Regarding upload speeds, see the comments to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56097768/2144390).